# How to trace from where exacly the missing asset was invoke in HTML page.

Tags: html, debugging, firebug

How can I trace missing files in HTML/Javascript? For example if my webpage is missing an asset I know that from Firebug console (beacose of server return error). But how Can I trace exacly in what file and line was this asset invoked?

Here is a example from Firebug
http://screencast.com/t/BWoc8UleqU

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no way to know exactly which module, file etc invoked the asset using firebug. If your using asp.net, then asset could be dynamically added either by code behind or something else which is plugged into the IIS pipeline. Same goes for any other framework. You have to do some detective work in your code files to get the answer.